# How to make the Android native music player scan it in time when the user adds music files midway

Tags: android, android-music-player

When adding MP3 files, android native music cannot display the newly added files in time. How to modify it to achieve it?

Comment: Have you considered Exoplayer?

Comment: I need to modify the Android native music apk. I don’t know if it needs to be modified in MediaPlaybackService.